# can I turn off window grouping with dockbarx?

Tags: dockbarx, prism

Is there any way to turn off window grouping with dockbarx? I use the Prism app to create standalone windows for gmail, my corporate webmail, and a few other sites. Because they all use Prism, instead of displaying as separate shortcuts with the custom icons I assigned to each when creating them, they all display together under a single Prism button, using the Prism icon.

Comment: Currently they are working on it.It will be available in next release.

Comment: Could you point me to where you found that? After I posted the question, I found a post from the author of the applet (link to which of course I can't find now) which states that he is never planning on doing this, as he thinks it's useless and completely goes against what dockbarx is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is interested in ungrouping Prism windows (this is ONLY for Prism), the DockbarX developer responded to another [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/19008/2664) of mine and indicated that he's hoping to include this functionality in the next release. Again, this is ONLY for Prism windows; he's not planning on allowing ungrouping of "normal" apps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I was unable to find an option to disable this behaviour, and I would suggest you report a bug to the dockbarx developers (if you don't want to let me know and I'll do it). The only option I could find was to show a window list, but since you are using launchers, you won't be able to accomplish this with Dockbarx.

You could however use a drawer on gnome-panel to achieve a somewhat similar effect (plus an extra click, unfortunately).