# Looking for information about upcoming dockbarx releases

Tags: dockbarx

I posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18528/can-i-turn-off-window-grouping-with-dockbarx) a while back asking about turning off grouping in Dockbarx. Someone left a comment indicating that it was being worked on and would be available in the next release, but that someone didn't provide any kind of documentation and I can't find anything online that supports the claim.

Has anyone seen anything that would indicate that ungrouping is, indeed, being added to the next release? If so, please provide a link to the source.

Comment: Try suggestion the feature at https://bugs.launchpad.net/dockbar/+filebug , you may get feedback from the developers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. But I don't want to suggest the feature; I want to know where it was apparently already documented that this is being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I - the developer - can answer you here as well.

Turning of grouping will as such will not happen as long as I'm in charge of DockbarX. I want to keep the consistency: a button on the task bar represents an application, not a window.

Your linked question is about prism, though. Since prism is web applications, different web applications should have their own button. I'm working on this. Hopefully it will make the next version (0.43) but until the code is written nothing is certain.

Comment: Thanks, Matias. I understand grouping multiple windows of a standalone app, but with Prism it doesn't make sense. Glad to hear it's at least on your radar.

Comment: Now it's implemented in 0.43. Prism apps should no longer be grouped toghether.